# Querying website and extracting output using excel input

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have a list of cell ranges within Excel that I'd like to input into a website search bar. Essentially, excel would take the content in a cell, go to the site, input the cell contents into the search tab on the site, and subsequently return the result of the search. I currently have code in place to go to the site:

```
Sub URL_Test()
strSearch = Range("a1")
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
                  Connection:="URL;https://www.siteexamle.com", _
                 Destination:=Range("a5"))

    .FieldNames = True
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With
End Sub
```

but am not sure how to have excel use the range from a cell as input into the search bar on the site. The html code responsible for the input that would need to be manipulated is:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="48" autofocus="autofocus">
```

where the cell content should be substituted for the **"value"** category. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you provide the website url? Is it public?

Comment: Yes, the website is https://mailtester.com/. The cell contents in excel would be the email address which would in turn be entered into the search bar on the site.

Comment: They have a batch e-mail tester which can use Excel as a data source. They also block "large volume checks" but don't say what qualifies.

Comment: I'm aware of their plugin. It's not effective. Approaching it from the VBA perspective I described would work far better. If you have advice on that, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: what would you expect as a return value?

Comment: @QHarr essentially the text output of the site after querying a sample email. If an email could not be verified, the site says "Server doesn't allow e-mail address verification." If an email was verified, the site says "E-mail address is valid." So extracting this output would be the primary goal.